# How to route according to REST Method in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a simple CRUD bulletin board using Express.

I want to do something like the following when a request comes in.

```
get /board/:id => show action
patch /board/:id => update action
delete /board/:id => delete action
```

But I do all the /board/:id requests with show action.

What's wrong with me?

**routes**

```
router.get("/:id", board.show);
router.patch("/:id", board.update);
router.delete("/:id", board.delete);
```

**view**

```
...
<a href=`/board/${board._id}`>show link</a>
<form action=`/board/${board._id}` method="patch">
<form action=`/board/${board._id` method="delete">
...
```

Comment: form `action` method supports only `GET` and `POSTS` requests. If you want to implement and others http VERBS you have to make AJAX requests

Comment: Is using method-overide npm a bad idea?

Comment: I've never used this. Always used `fetch` or jquery AJAX request.